# There are two periodic functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, provide an example when $f(x)*g(x)$ is unbounded, and $f(x)+g(x)=0$ has infinitely many solutions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

There are two periodic functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ which are defined on $\mathbb{R}$, provide an example when $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ is unbounded, and $f(x)+g(x)=0$ has infinitely many solutions ?

Comment: what kind of periodic unbounded functions do you know?

Answer (score 5):

Take any unbounded periodic function $f$ and put $g=-f.$
For example you can take $$f(t)=\begin{cases} \tan t \mbox{ if } t\notin \frac{\pi}{2} +\pi\mathbb{Z} \\ 0 \mbox{ if } t\in \frac{\pi}{2} +\pi\mathbb{Z}\end{cases}$$

Comment: You wanna say that sum of f+g=0 will give function that has infinitely many solutions?